# JSON в JAVA с использованием GSON библиотеки

Tags: java, json, парсер

```
{"logs":
   [
   {"ch":"C","lvl":-2,"msg":"Console v2.6 build 611. PlugIn WIN
   18,0,0,194."},
   {"ch":"-","lvl":2,"msg":"version 1.1 r111 DEBUG"},
   {"ch":"External calls","lvl":2,"msg":"ExternalInterface.available: true"}
   ],
"length":3}
```

Помогите распарсить такой JSON в JAVA с использованием GSON библиотеки

Comment: В чем именно затруднение?

Comment: В создании класса со структурой ответа,
 
`Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyClassForJSONParse [] resp = gson.fromJson(json, MyClassForJSONParse[].class);
        for (int i = 0; i < resp.length; i++)
        {
            String name = resp[i].getLogs()
        }`
вот так пытаюсь распарсить, но не могу понять что должно быть в MyClassForJSONParse[].class

Comment: Не пишите JAVA, надо писать Java и не GSON, а Gson. Да я [граммар-наци](http://lurkmore.to/Grammar_nazi)

Comment: Обязательно учту, спасибо за советы, теперь буду разбираться что я делаю не так и почему не получается)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, нужно сделать два оборачивающих класса:

- один для самого ответа

  ```
  public class Log {
      private List<LogRecord> logs;
      private Integer length;

      public List<LogRecord> getLogs() {
          return logs;
      }

      public void setLogs(List<LogRecord> logs) {
          this.logs = logs;
      }

      public Integer getLength() {
          return length;
      }

      public void setLength(Integer length) {
          this.length = length;
      }
  }
  ```
- и один для записей в коллекции `logs`

  ```
  public class LogRecord {
      private String ch;
      private Integer lvl;
      private String msg;

      public String getCh() {
          return ch;
      }

      public void setCh(String ch) {
          this.ch = ch;
      }

      public Integer getLvl() {
          return lvl;
      }

      public void setLvl(Integer lvl) {
          this.lvl = lvl;
      }

      public String getMsg() {
          return msg;
      }

      public void setMsg(String msg) {
          this.msg = msg;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Разобрался. Теперь все работает отлично)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь участвуют 2 класса:

```
class MyClass1 {
   Logs[] logs;
   int length;
}

class Logs {
   String ch;
   int lvl;
   String msg;
}
```

Остальное дело техники.